# Ruby on Rails and MSSQL Server: trying to insert rows with newid() default values

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, uniqueidentifier

(this question was originally posted in another forum a few months ago, without getting any answer ... there was no SO at these times!)

My first steps in RoR. I baught one of these books talking about Ruby, and Ruby On Rails. Examples are running correctly on MySQL, so I decided to rewrite them for MS-SQL as a good exercice (and as MS-SQL is our standard database).. and it turned into a bad dream:

I have this table with 2 fields

```
Tbl_People
----------
id_People        primary key, newid() default value,
namePeople       string
```

I have an ODBC connection to the database. I can list the records, but ... I cannot make any inserts in the table. The INSERT string generated by Ruby is the following:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_People (id_People, namePeople) VALUES('newid','GRONDIER, Philippe')
```

And will be refused because the string 'newid' cannot be inserted in the uniqueindentifier/primary key field `id_People`. Logically, the error returned is:

```
DBI::DatabaseError: 37000 (8169) [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier
```

It seems to be so obviously a big and basic problem that I feel I missed something usually written in bold on each RoR training document such as 'Don't try INSERTs through RoR','uniqueIdentifier is Chinese to RoR', or 'RoR doesn't work with MS SQL Server'...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby guy, so just keep that in mind.  Most of this is just lost in the MySQL->MSSQL translation IMO.

So, your id is of type "uniqueidentifier".  One of two things should happen:

a) you should pass in NEWID() as the first parameter.  Not the string 'newid', but the function NEWID()

b) don't pass in the first param.  Since there is a default value, just insert into the NamePeople column.

Depending on usage, I'd only use uniqueidentifier primary keys if you are dealing with distributed data, and stick to good old INT IDENTITY columns for most key references.

Comment: the INSERT string is automatically generated by RUBY, not by me. The way RUBY generate the string is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post, different db type, but essentially the same issue, how to conceal defaulted fields from RoR so an invalid insert isn't generated.

**EDIT** @wayne-conrad pointed out the old link was dead. I believe the content was that which is found here, 
http://inodes.org/2008/01/11/rails-activerecord-mysql-guids-and-the-rename_column-bug/

Key excerpt below.

The comments section of the page also references a project intended to remedy the problem 
https://github.com/cch1/uuid_primary_key/tree/master (links don't fail me now!)

```
 # HACK (JF) - This is too evil to even blog about
  # When we use guid as a primary key we usually rename the original 'id'
  # field to 'integer_id'. We need to hide this from rails so it doesn't
  # mess with it. WARNING: This means once you use usesguid anywhere you can
  # never access a column in any table anywhere called 'integer_id'

class ActiveRecord::Base
  private
    alias :original_attributes_with_quotes :attributes_with_quotes

    def attributes_with_quotes(include_primary_key = true, include_readonly_attributes = true)
      quoted = original_attributes_with_quotes(include_primary_key = true, include_readonly_attributes = true)
      quoted.delete('integer_id')
      quoted
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem exposed in this blog is quite different but still of generic interest. After reading this, I might like to build a function to generate uniqueId values on the client-side

Comment: Sadly, the  link is dead now.